# How to redirect Login link in password_reset_complete Django

Tags: python, django

Login link in password_reset_complete directs the user to accounts/login rather than account/login. How do I solve this?

Error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in tutorial.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
[name='login_redirect']
admin/
account/
The current path, accounts/login/, didn't match any of these.
```

accounts/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [

path('', views.home, name="home"),
path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'), name='login'),
path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html'), name='logout'),
path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
path('profile/', views.view_profile, name='profile'),
path('profile/edit/', views.edit_profile, name='profile-edit'),
path('change-password/', views.change_password, name='change-password'),
path('reset-password/', PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='reset-password'),
path('reset-password/done/', PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
path('reset-password/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
path('reset-password/complete/', PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
```

main/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path(r'', views.login_redirect, name='login_redirect'),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('account/', include('accounts.urls')),
```

]

settings.py:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/account/'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you've defined wrong url pattern

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', views.login_redirect, name='login_redirect'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')), # use "accounts" instead of "account"
]
```

### Note

Now onwards, your all **`/account/..`** urls will be changed to **`/accounts/...`**

Comment: Page not found (404)
      Request Method: GET
      Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/login/
      Using the URLconf defined in tutorial.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in      this order:
     [name='login_redirect']
     admin/
     accounts/
     The current path, account/login/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: Now onwards, you should use **`/accounts/...`** instead of `/account/...`